# Numerical Optimization of n-multivariable function

Tags: functions, optimization

Hi I am an electrical engineer and I am very out of my depth with this. In my work I came across an odd optimization problem I am not sure how to tackle. Below I described my strategy but it is tough to say the least.

$$\begin{align*}
 \min\quad & \int_{Xa}^{Xb} F(x,s(g))dx\\
\quad
\text{where}\\
 &F= (\sum_{i}^n \frac{1}{(x-s_i)})^{-2} \\
\text{s.t}\\
 &s_n>s_{n-1}>...s_1>0\\
\text{&}\\
&X_b>X_a>0
\end{align*}$$

so I am attempting to find the function $$s(g)$$ (or a bunch of s_i in discrete terms) such that it minimizes F(x,S) along the integral.

I could not figure out how to do this in the continuous limit so what I was going to try and do is solve it in summation form by picking n points along x between Xa and Xb and setting it up to optimize for just those points ie: $$F(x,s_i)=0$$ at 
$$x=X_a,X_a+d,...X_b$$. Where d is some step size. Then I was going to set up a system of linear equations replacing any $$s_1*s_2*...s_n$$ with $$S_{1,2,3...n}$$ then solving for a specific set of s_i s.t none of them can be negative and that they satisfy the above conditions. I was attempting this because I could not find a way to solve the continuous limit. Even in the discrete limit I get multiple solutions for each s (as expected I just pick one set). So... am I on the right track or is there a better way to attempt this?

EDIT: If anyone attempts this or runs into this problem. I solved this by using a genetic algorithm for multifunction optimization. The Objective functions were $F(x_m,)$ defined as $X_a<x_m<X_b$ and m points are equally spaced. The real stipulation so that I do not miss any of the zero/pole points, was to make $m>>n$ and then plotted the function to make sure none were missed. A much more efficient way could be done by setting bounds on each variable, but I just brute forced it this way.

Comment: Where are your $s_i$s coming from? Also, if you could clean up your formatting (try to avoid using \text{} in your TeX) a bit so it's more easily readable, much appreciated.

Comment: Si is to be determined by me, they are the discrete version of points in s(g). So as n goes to inf, $$s_i$$ goes to $$s(g)$$. I will try and clean it up a bit, been years since I used tex for anything so am stumbling back through it.

Comment: Are there any constraints on $s$? In particular, can you ever have $x_a<s_i<x_b$?

Comment: no constraints on S in terms of x, only constraint I have is that $s_{i}>s_{i-1}>...>0$

Comment: And $x_a>0$ as well? (The point is that your $F$ does something slightly strange when $x$ is close to $s_i$, and is presumably defined to be $0$ when $x=s_i$.)

Comment: Doesn't $F$ go to infinity if, for example, $n=2$ and $x=(s_1+s_2)/2$? Your integral is undefined.

Comment: yes sorry $X_b>X_a>0$ and you see the weird issue I have is that F tries to blow up but must be minimized as it is blowing up at points along x

Comment: Ah yes, $F$ also blows up when the terms try to cancel each other out. That is a problem. In particular it will make a naive discrete approximation completely useless. You will have to carefully work around the possible singularities.

Comment: @Ian Yes, any advice for trying to work around the singularities? Even a book recommendation would be great as I am very out of my depth with this. Thank you for the help btw

Comment: Well, I think a good first thing to try would be to get a feel for how the numbers work out if you choose all the $s_i$ to be outside of $[x_a,x_b]$. This is bad in the sense that it makes each term in the sum for $F$ small (so the reciprocal of the sum is large), but it is good in the sense that it prevents cancellations, which could potentially make $F$ very big in some regions. Then you can see how that compares to other values.

Comment: I don't know of a way to deal with what happens when the $s_i$ are between $x_a$ and $x_b$ (where you have to balance making the individual terms bigger against having them cancel each other out, all the while dodging singularities at every turn).

Comment: @Ian Thanks I will try and see how it behaves, I actually have an odd idea to try as well, you made me think of it in terms of it's spectral response which may be easier to deal with for minimization.